# xslt analyze string not allowing "value-of" selection

Tags: xslt

```
In the template below I'm trying to grab some information from an existing XML document and to re-write that same document with the addition of some specific ids.
```

Here's a snippet of the xml:

```
<item id='ta-' type='articulus'>
   <fileName filestem='ta-'>ta-.xml</fileName>
   <title>Super Sent., lib. 1 d. 1 q. 3 a. 1 tit.</title>
   <questionTitle>Utrum utendum sit omnibus aliis a Deo</questionTitle>
</item>
```

In the template below, the regular expression works great. However the attempt to rebuild  and  fails. Saxon tells me 'XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string'. I'm not sure what that means. But I think, after the "analyze-string' element, I'm no longer on the correct node in my tree to successfully perform the "value-of" selections. (See the template below). Thanks for your help.

```
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="./title" regex="([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="fs"><xsl:value-of select="concat('ta-l', regex-group(1) ,'d', regex-group(2) ,'q', regex-group(3),'a',regex-group(4))"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
            <item xml:id="{$fs}">
                <fileName filestem='{$fs}'><xsl:value-of select="concat($fs, '.xml')"/></fileName>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></title>
                <questionTitle><xsl:value-of select="./questionTitle"/></questionTitle>
            </item>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the context node outside of the `analyze-string` with

```
<xsl:variable name="item" select="."/>
```

then inside of the analyze-string you can use

```
            <title><xsl:value-of select="$item/title"/></title>
            <questionTitle><xsl:value-of select="$item/questionTitle"/></questionTitle>
```